# Which permissions TFS should contain on SQL Server after your first installation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs, permissions

DBA needs to remove some TFS 2013 permissions from SQL Server 2012. Which permissions TFS should contain on SQL Server after your first installation? FULL TFS has been installed

SQL Server permissions to first TFS installation I've found but daily permission I couldn't

Another specifics questions are:

- Can we remove Optimize Database Job (Release Management)?
  This TFS job basically executes Update Statistics and as we are working with shared SQL Server,  this routing already exists on our DB
- What is impact for TFS to remove "Agent User Role" from MSDB database?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: This might be better on the MSDN TFS forums where you are more likely to find MS Tech Staff.

Answer (score 0):

You can check these two links for the details about Database Permissions requirements for TFS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552341.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/08/20/database-permissions-required-to-configure-tfs.aspx

The followings are some highlight points for your quick reference:

1. sysadmin and serveradmin for all databases that TFS uses.
2. CREATE DATABASE - We need this permission to be able to create configuration, collection, and warehouse database.
3. Reporting Services: Team Foundation Content Manager and either sysadmin or the db_owner group membership for the configuration database, the reporting and analysis databases, and the databases for team project collections.
4. If you want the user to have sufficient permissions to create a database as part of creating a team project collection, you must grant that user membership in the sysadmin role in SQL Server
5. To install, upgrade, and configure TFS, the user running the Team Foundation Administration console requires the following permissions and role memberships. 
   -Membership in the serveradmin server role
   -ALTER ANY LOGIN, CREATE ANY DATABASE, and VIEW ANY DEFINITION server scoped permissions
   -CONTROL permission on the master database

In addition, I don't it is a good idea to remove the Optimize Database job; and I think it is OK to remove the SQLAgentUserRole, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: The links are dead